# Don't understand how the XCode project knows how to start with the Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I'm looking into iOS development. I've setup a tab bar project with the tab bar template. Few things I don't get. (I've attached a screen shot showing what I'm seeing)

[image: Tab view project, first view]

1. I don't see where the tab bar controller is told to start/do anything from the code created in the template? There's just the AppDelegate, the view controllers and that's it?
2. How would I get a table view to be displayed in the tab views? When I try to drag a table view onto the first view controller it doesn't let me.
3. Ideally I would use one of the Parse.com's table view subclasses for my table view, I presume I would have to set that up with code from one of the tab views viewdidload?
4. You can see on the left that a LaunchScreen.xib was created, but where is this screen run from? I can see no reference to it anywhere else in the project. How is it controlled? what tells it to appear and then to disappear?

Comment: You should read the "View Controller Programming Guide of iOS". The section called "Using View Controllers in Your App" explains what happens at startup.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on the Tab Bar Controller and in the View Controller properties click "Is Initial View Controller"
2. Double click on the first view controller, then drag a Table View onto the View Controller. Add a Table View Cell to the Table View.
3. If you want to use PFQueryTableViewController you should add a Table View Controller to the story board then connect. Do a Ctrl+Click Drag from the Tab Bar Controller to the new Table View Controller and select relationship segue > view controllers. In the .h file of your Table View Controller change UITableViewController to PFQueryTableViewController.

Here is a good tutorial that helped me: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I added a table view and then a cell to it, and positioned it in the center, but when I run the code, the table view is positined off to the right?

Comment: You should line the table View inside the View Controller exactly (you will see blue horizontal/vertical lines when it is aligned). You could even use auto layout to Pin Leading, Top, Bottom, Trailing Space to Superview. You could also just delete that View Controller and start with a Table View Controller as everything is already done for you. This would be easier as starting with a view controller will add some extra steps because you will have to hook up the table view delegates to the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the project file an then your target. Under general->Deployment info there is a entry Main Interface where you specify the main storyboard. And under Supporting Files (in the project navigator) there is the info.plist file where launch screen and main storyboard in defined.
2. I would change the type of the first view controller to a table view controller.
3. You can just drag a regular uitableviewcontroller in to the storyboard and then Identity Inspector in the right panel you can change the type to use the Parse.com's tableview type.
4. The Launchscreen as a .xib is new to iOS8 and is the view that is displayed while your app is starting. It used to be you could only supply a image.